Transition to full screen in YouTube on a mobile browser via JS
I have an android app that uses YouTube inside a WebView, and uses WebView.evaluateJavascript() to control the video player. For example, autoplay next short when the current one ends, using edge taps to change the video, etc. It does this by using ARIA labels. Everything works just fine except I can't seem to get full screen working.
The JS code is document.querySelector("[aria-label='Enter full screen']").click();, which works just fine on a desktop browser set to send a mobile user string. However, the code fails silently in app. It doesn't even "crash" the JS file.
Any help would be appreciated.
Just to be clear, this is not an embedded browser, neither is this using official YouTube JS API
